# Нужно получить ответ от локального сервера

Tags: php, json, fetch, file-get-contents

Я хочу отправить на Локальный сервер(OpenServer) форму с помощью Fetch и получить в ответ имя которое было записано в соответствующий input. Так же что бы в дальнейшем можно было записывать данные в SQL таблицу. Но пока ответ такой Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0.

```
<form id="formSendQuestion">
                    <div class="askingForms__yourNameWorkLive">
                        <input type="text" id="invisible__input" name="topicOfQuestion" value='Оплата и нормирование труда'>
                        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Как вас зовут?">
                        <input type="text" name="where__Living" placeholder="Где вы живете?">
                        <input type="text" name="where__working" placeholder="Место работы?">
                    </div>
                    <div class="enterInThisFieldYourQuestion">
                        <textarea placeholder="Введите в это поле ваш вопрос.?" name="questionText" id="" cols="30"
                            rows="10"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sendEmailAndFile">
                        <div>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="sendEmailAndFile" id="sendEmailAndFile"
                                class="custom-checkbox">
                            <label for="sendEmailAndFile" class="labelForEmail">Выслать ответ на мою электронную
                                почту.</label>
                            <input type="text" name="yourEmail"
                                placeholder="Впишите сюда адрес вашей почты: например, ivanov@mail.ru">
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <div>
                                <input type="file" name="picture" id="picture">
                                <label for="picture" class="labelForFileInput">Добавить файл</label>
                                <p class="you_can_upload_files" id="fileInfo">Вы можете приложить дополнительные
                                    материалы, более полно раскрывающие суть вопроса.
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <p class="FileSizeNoMore" id="fileInfo">Размер файла не более 5 МБ в форматах TXT, DOC, RTF,
                                PDF.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="twoLastCheckbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="myPersonalData" id="myPersonalData" class="custom-checkbox">
                        <label for="myPersonalData" class="labelForEmail">Я не хочу, чтобы мои персональные данные были
                            видны на сайте. Их увидит только специалист, отвечая на вопрос. </label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="agreeOnOperations" id="agreeOnOperations" class="custom-checkbox">
                        <label for="agreeOnOperations" class="labelForEmail" id="agreeOnOperationsLabel">Согласен на
                            обработку персональных данных.</label>
                    </div>

                    <p id="sendQuestionButton" class="opacityStyele" value=false data-hr="fd">Отправить вопрос</p>

                </form> 

function sendForm(){
           
        
            fetch('assets/php/conecter.php', {/////////////////// отправка формы
              method: 'POST',
              body: new FormData(formSendQuestion),
              headers: {
                  'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
              },  
              
            }).then((response) => {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then((response) => {
               console.log(response); 
            })
            .finally();
          };

<?php,
    $postData = file_get_contents('C:\OpenServer\domains\test\assets\php\conecter.php');
    $data = json_decode($postData, true);
    
    $name = var_dump($data["name"]);


      
    echo json_encode($name);
?>
```

Comment: Можете пояснить самому себе, что вы тут делаете `$name = var_dump($data["name"]);` ?

Comment: ну я получил массив на подобие POST и потом из него по ключу name пытаюсь получить значение. Так мне кажется

Comment: при помощи var_dump?

Comment: я находил похожий вопрос где было такое решение. И яя просто скапировал код оттуда

Comment: Ну тогда попробуйте поискать инфу что делает var_dump и как надо получить значение из массива